# Upload folder of CSV'S to Google Sheet using Python

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am amateur in python and Google API. I have to create script which uploads all CSV from folder to Google Drive as sheets. So far I have this script which uses gspread to upload one csv file to one specified Google Sheet. I have a lot of those CSV and I need to upload them as sheets to google drive. I am not able find a solution to deal with multiple CSV files.

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/krzysztofpaszta/credentials.json')

content = open('ONETTF-Projects-INFO.csv', 'r').read().encode('utf-8') 

gc.import_csv('1gv-bKe-flo5FwIbt_xgCp1vNn0L0KBnpiu', content)
```

All of information is about uploading one csv file. Could someone give me some hint how to manage to upload folder with csv files such that all files as saved in Google Drive as sheets?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
As @metamorporpoise suggested I have modified the script, I am very very close because I can see looking at the sheet in google drive that the script is actually uploading all of my CSV but in the same moment it is replacing imported CSV with new one. That's because those files are uploading on the same sheet.

```
import gspread
import os
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/krzysztofpaszta/credentials.json')

os.chdir('/users/krzysztofpaszta/CSVtoGD')

files = os.listdir()

for filename in files:
   if filename.split(".")[1] == "csv":
      content = open(filename, 'r').read().encode('utf-8') 
      gc.import_csv('1gv-bKe-flo5FwIbt_xgCp1vNn0L0KBnpiuRak9a1efQ', content)
```

Is there a way to modify the gc.import_csv to import those files to different sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not entirely familiar with the gspread package, I do know that the os package would be very helpful for iterating through files in a folder. You would not need to install os, as it should already come with Python. You can use it like so:

```
import gspread
import os
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='/users/krzysztofpaszta/credentials.json')

os.chdir(FOLDER_PATH)

files = os.listdir()

for filename in files:
   if filename.split(".")[1] == "csv":
      content = open(filename, 'r').read().encode('utf-8') 
      gc.import_csv('1gv-bKe-flo5FwIbt_xgCp1vNn0L0KBnpiu', content)
```

You would need to replace `FOLDER_PATH` with the path to the folder you are storing the csv's in relative to the directory you are running your python script in. The `if filename.split(".")[1] == "csv":` line is there to ensure that the script only tries to upload csv files and ignores any other type of file. I am not entirely familiar with what the first argument in the gc.import_csv() command is doing, so that might cause an issue if it is specific to the particular csv you were trying to upload before. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Upon looking into the import_csv() function, it seems that my current code would just continuously overwrite the same spreadsheet over and over. It seems like you would need to create new spreadsheets for every file and then pass in the `file_id` as the argument to `import_csv()` each time

EDIT2: Try adding this line after the if statement:
`sh = gc.create(filename.split(".")[0])` and then replacing the long string that is currently the first argument of import_csv() with `sh.id`. I hope this works!

Comment: thank you for your help. I have modified the script and actually it is working but it's importing all of my CSV to the same sheet so they are replaced by new one until the last CSV in folder. Maybe you have some idea how to make this script to upload every csv to different sheet? Thank you so far one more time :)

Comment: I didn't see this comment but I just made an edit to my original post!

Comment: I have made a second edit to my original answer which should fix that issue!

Comment: oh man. it is working.. I was trying to achieve that for few days and modify a 100-lines codes of other people swearing like hell... Thank you so much. Although I have one question because as I can see you know much more about those modules than me :p right now the script is saving all csv to my main folder. Is there a way to change it in easy way?

Comment: I'm very glad to be of help and save some time! Unfortunately, I think creating directories is certainly out of the scope of the gspread. I actually have never used gspread, but have considerable practice with os. I found this tutorial (https://calvinowens.medium.com/how-to-manage-google-sheets-with-python-and-gspread-7158cb6a444b) that might be helpful to you, but it seems pretty involved. It might just be easier to manually drag all those new files in your recent folder into a folder yourself.